# Converting from struct timespec to std::chrono::?

Tags: c++, time, c++-chrono

I've got a stream of struct timespec values.  I'd like to convert them to a native C++11 representation, but I'm totally turned around by chrono.  What is the best destination and how to get there from a struct timespec or struct timeval since that is an easy transformation and micro seconds is good enough for these timings?  I presume that I want to be getting to this, right?
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point

In this case, the `timespec` is UNIX time from a GPS.  And yes, they are using a 4 byte second (converted form signed in memory and then written as unsigned) that will get nailed by 2038.

For reference, I'll be adding this to the C++ reader for [gsf](https://github.com/schwehr/generic-sensor-format/issues/55)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Sometimes I see `timespec` and `timeval` used as durations, and sometimes I see them used as time points.  You will have to know what kind of values you are holding.  In `<chrono>` these two concepts are different types.

A duration is an amount of time:  something you would measure with a stopwatch.  Example durations are 2 minutes, 3 seconds, 4 hours, and 16 years.

A time point is a specific time:  2pm Jul 14, 2015 EDT, or 6 hours since I booted up my computer.  A time point has an implied epoch associated with it.  An epoch is just some mutually agreed upon origin with which you're measuring time from.

If your `timespec` holds a duration:

```
timespec ts = {3, 123};  // 3 seconds + 123 nanoseconds
auto d = std::chrono::seconds{ts.seconds}
       + std::chrono::nanoseconds{ts.nanoseconds};
```

If your `timespec` holds a time point, you have to know the epoch.  It is likely that the epoch is 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, neglecting leap seconds (this is [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)).  If so, you can put it into a `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point`.  This type is *not* guaranteed to have this epoch, but every implementation does:

```
using namespace std::chrono;
system_clock::time_point tp{duration_cast<system_clock::duration>(d)};
```

where `d` is computed as above.

If you have a `timeval`, then use `microseconds` where I've used `nanoseconds`.

You can not portably use `high_resolution_clock` or `steady_clock` time_points because different implementations have different epochs for these types.

Also if you're using `timeval`, in practice the `duration_cast` becomes unnecessary as the duration `d` will implicitly convert to all implementations of `system_clock::duration`:

```
using namespace std::chrono;
system_clock::time_point tp{d};
```

If you aren't sure if you need the `duration_cast` or not, try it without.  If it compiles, you don't need it.  If you get a compile-time error, you do need it.  It is needed when converting durations and there is not an exact conversion.

Comment: `std::chrono::system_clock` has the convenience methods `from_time_t` and `to_time_t`. These should assure a more portable conversion, if we're talking about `time_points`.

Comment: @user666412:  Yes.  I put `from_time_t` and `to_time_t` into C++11. :-)  Unfortunately `time_t` is usually both integral and represents seconds, whereas both `timespec` and `timeval` represent units finer than a second.  So going through `to/from_time_t` means that you have to truncate your precision to seconds, and then somehow recover that precision.  Between you and me, the benefit of `to/from_time_t` is that it encouraged implementors to use the UnixTime "standard" for `system_clock`. :-)

Comment: Interesting fact. Thank you for sharing. I just thought of `to/from_time_t` as a portable way to adjust the epoch, since that can be implementation specific, and the fractions of seconds may be added the same way as you did with duration.

Comment: @user666412:  You are correct that the use of `to/from_time_t` is the only standard-blessed way to do this today.  I am working on standardizing the epoch of `system_clock` to UnixTime.  I have the personal assurances of all the implementors that they will do this.  But that of course is not official and only good until the implementors change, or the standard locks it in.  Currently my proposal to lock in this epoch includes a bunch of other things, making it very high risk: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0355r1.html#Wording

Comment: C++20 fixes the epoch of `system_clock` to match that of [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time): http://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.system#overview-1