# Converting from std::chrono:: to 32 bit seconds and nanoseconds?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, c++14

This could be the inverse of [Converting from struct timespec to std::chrono::?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31409036/converting-from-struct-timespec-to-stdchrono#:%7E:text=timespec%20ts%20%3D%20%7B3%2C%20123%7D%3B%20%2F%2F%203%20seconds,UTC%2C%20neglecting%20leap%20seconds%20%28this%20is%20Unix%20time%29.)

I am getting my time as

```
const std::Chrono::CRealTimeClock::time_point RealTimeClockTime = std::Chrono::CRealTimeClock::now();
```

and I have to convert it to a `struct timespec`.

Actually, I don't, if there is an altrerntive; what I have to do is get the number of seconds since the epoch and the number of nanoseconds since the last last second.

I chose `struct timespec` becuase

```
struct timespec
{
    time_t tv_sec;  // Seconds - >= 0
    long   tv_nsec; // Nanoseconds - [0, 999999999]
};
```

The catch is that I need to shoehorn the seconds and nonseconds into `uint32_t`.

I am aware theat there is a danger of loss of precision, but reckon that we don't care too much about the nanoseconds while the [year 208 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) gives me cause for concern.

However, I have to bang out some code now and we can update it later if necessary. The code has to meet another manufacturer's specification and it is likely to take weeks or months to get this problem resolved and use `uint64_t`.

So, how can I, right now, obtain 32 bit values of second and nanosecond from `std::Chrono::CRealTimeClock::now()`?

Comment: `std::Chrono` is not a valid namespace, and you're *not* allowed to put whatever you want into namespace `std`. Doing so yields undefined behavior.

Comment: My apologies.GI changed it to avoid naming a company internal class which inherits from  Chron. Guess I made a mistake :-(   Thanks for pointing it out (+1)

Comment: Although, ...  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to ignore `std::Chrono::CRealTimeClock::now()` and just pretend you wrote `std::chrono::system_clock::now()`.  Hopefully that will give you the tools to deal with whatever clock you actually have.

Assume:

```
#include <cstdint>

struct my_timespec
{
    std::uint32_t tv_sec;  // Seconds - >= 0
    std::uint32_t tv_nsec; // Nanoseconds - [0, 999999999]
};
```

Now you can write:

```
#include <chrono>

my_timespec
now()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    auto tp = system_clock::now();
    auto tp_sec = time_point_cast<seconds>(tp);
    nanoseconds ns = tp - tp_sec;
    return {static_cast<uint32_t>(tp_sec.time_since_epoch().count()),
            static_cast<uint32_t>(ns.count())};
}
```

Explanation:

- I've used function-local using directives to reduce code verbosity and increase readability.  If you prefer you can use using declarations instead to bring individual names into scope, or you can explicitly qualify everything.
- The first job is to get `now()` from whatever clock you're using.
- Next use `std::chrono::time_point_cast` to truncate the precision of `tp` to `seconds` precision.  One important note is that `time_point_cast` truncates towards zero.  So this code assumes that `now()` is *after* the clock's epoch and returns a non-negative `time_point`.  If this is not the case, then you should use C++17's `floor` instead. `floor` always truncates towards negative infinity.  I chose `time_point_cast` over `floor` only because of the [c++14] tag on the question.
- The expression `tp - tp_sec` is a `std::chrono::duration` representing the time duration since the last integral second.  This duration is implicitly converted to have units of `nanoseconds`.  This implicit conversion is typically fine as all implementations of `system_clock::duration` have units that are either `nanoseconds` or coarser (and thus implicitly convertible to) `nanoseconds`.  If your clock tracks units of `picoseconds` (for example), then you will need a `duration_cast<nanoseconds>(tp - tp_sec)` here to truncate `picoseconds` to `nanoseconds` precision.
- Now you have the `{seconds, nanoseconds}` information in `{tp_sec, ns}`.  It's just that they are still in `std::chrono` types and not `uint32_t` as desired.  You can extract the internal integral values with the member functions `.time_since_epoch()` and `.count()`, and then `static_cast` those resultant integral types to `uint32_t`.  The final `static_cast` are optional as integral conversions can be made implicitly.  However their use is considered good style.

Comment: Thanks, Howard. As I mentioned in a comment, I changed a little to avoid posting a company proprietary class name, which basically just wraps the std:: and nothing else. Obviously, I goofed. But you manage despite that, so I am more than happy to accept your answer.